# Mean Stack: Refreshing or entering a direct URL lead to 'Cannot GET/'?

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, angular5

I have created a webpage using MEAN stack. Angular 5.

One problem I am having is that I cannot enter in the direct url path. for example, If i entered in /home at the end, I get this error message "Cannot GET /home". This happens when I hit refresh too. The page working perfectly If i click on 'home' navigation button from my home page.

For example:
This is my page: https://nameless-hollows-54410.herokuapp.com/

When I go to a direct link, https://nameless-hollows-54410.herokuapp.com/home

The page is broken. Why is this happening?

My app-routing code:

```
const routes: Routes  = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
];
```

My Nav bar:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home
       <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with your host configuration, did you configure your rewrites correctly?

Comment: What do you mean? I dont think i have change much. I followed this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me explain a few things.

It's not a front-end issue. When you are invoking the '***/home***' from your angular application by clicking the link it's working fine. Because your angular app knows the route.

But on directly invoke the '***my-site-address/home***', it is trying to find the route of '***/home***' in your node app. Since there is no '***/home***' route in your node application, it's a dead end.

So the problem is when you directly invoke '***my-site-address/home***', the '***/home***' do not reach to the front-end routing, instead, it is trying to route through the node application.

> To solve the problem, for each route, from your node app, you have to
>   load the build file(for angular maybe it is 'index.html').

To do so, make sure, for any unknown routes, your node app load the index.html(angular build) file.

Your code in node js routing should be similar like this.

```
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'angular build file path'));
});
```

Put the routing to the last section of your router.

Also, replace the 'angular build file path' by the angular build file path, in your case maybe 'index.html file path'.

You can also check the [source code](https://github.com/bmshamsnahid/Photopher-api/blob/master/server.js)(focus on line 78 and the project structure).

Comment: It's a pleasure to help you.